# How to listen to already existing SQS queue with Celery and Django?

Tags: python, django, celery, amazon-sqs

I want to listen to an existing SQS queue through Celery.
I have already done publishing to Queue via celery and then consuming from that queue through workers and tasks bound to that queue.
However, I am unable to figure out how to consume from an SQS queue if the publisher is a non-celery Django application. There is no such information available on the internet regarding this or at least I am unable to locate it. Can someone please guide me to some documentation for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you want to do I have bad news for you - it is not possible. Celery can only consume own messages. If your Django application needs to send some task to the Celery cluster using SQS as broker, it needs to instantiate a Celery application object, and use it to send tasks.

Comment: Thanks @DejanLekic for answering. At this time I am more keen towards listening to messages from SQS published by some other applications.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use Celery. I would use `boto3` directly, in a custom Django management command, to long-poll the queue and parse / route the incoming messages.

Celery would give you nothing, and would only increase the complexity of implementation.